# Codeigniter session is not saved after redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have array with a information about user:  `$authdata`
The array is not empty.

So, after add array to session:

```
$this->session->set_userdata($authdata);
```

And after do redirect:

```
redirect('profile');
```

I get empty session on page `profile.php`

If do echo all session after I get full session:

```
$this->session->set_userdata($authdata);
echo $this->session->userdata['type']; // Get all session fields
```

But after redirect `echo $this->session->userdata['type'];` gives me **false**

Comment: if this is `echo $this->session->userdata['type']`, then why do you have to post that as _not working_ ? anyway you should post that part that concerns the problem.

Comment: check session data by `echo "<pre>";   prin_r($this->session->all_userdata());`

Comment: I tried your advice, so session there is (`session_id`), but with a empty field `user_data`, at `user_data` must be array `$authdata`

Comment: What do you have in `$authdata`? Could you do a `print_r()` of it?

Comment: Yes, before `$this->session->set_userdata($authdata);` :  `Array ( [username] =>  Balmus [logged_in] => 1 [id_user] => 483 [status] => 1 [type] => 1 [timezone] => -240 )`

Comment: has the controller globally access to session? https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Session is loaded by autoload.php in settings. I must say, that if open link `profile` without `redirect()` to `profile` - IT opens this page, so session works, but if do redirect - not

Comment: There a unset_userdata or set_flashdata? your are using databse store session? can you edit the question and put the whole function?

Comment: Yes, I use `set_flashdata()` and DB store